# Make theme settings support multisite enabled (WordPress Mu) site

Tags: themes, theme-development, multisite

recently I found a problem is that all custom theme settings written by theme author are not working for a multisite enabled site. I've checked several themes and thought this workaround may help:

```
add_theme_page('lindsay-koinaka', 'lindsay-koinaka', 'edit_themes', 'lindsay-koinaka', 'lindsay_koinaka_admin_page_init');
```

Then I changed it to:

```
add_theme_page('lindsay-koinaka', 'lindsay-koinaka', 'switch_themes', 'lindsay-koinaka', 'lindsay_koinaka_admin_page_init');
```

But hen I try to change settings I got the following message:

You do not have sufficient permissions to modify unregistered settings for this site.

So how to make theme settings support multisite enabled site? anybody has good ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See this post:

http://wpmututorials.com/known-issues/did-your-users-theme-options-and-widgets-page-disappear/

Basically, pick a different cap until it works. Also see:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: Yeah I tried to change it to `edit_theme_options` or even `read`, but nothing help.